# how should i code my java so that submit button be active only after a checkbutton is selected in android app

Tags: java, android

Am working on an App project. As in my xml file I want the submit button to be active only after a radio button is checked in the radio group of xml file so that another activity is accessed . Would be glad for help.

```
<RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/rg9">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/richardOmtata"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:text="@string/richardOmtata"
                android:textColor="#fdfbfe64"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/vincentKamama"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:text="@string/vincentKamama"
                android:textColor="#fdfbfe64"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/peterRotich"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:text="@string/peterRotich"
                android:textColor="#fdfbfe64"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/victorOlentimama"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:text="@string/victorOlentimama"
                android:textColor="#fdfbfe64"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


        </RadioGroup>
        <Button
            android:onClick="submit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/submitButton"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:textColor="#ff090909"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="#ff0fc0ff" />
```

Comment: Can you not just use the nice css 'ng-disabled' extra's on that button Angular? See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled#!

Answer (score 0):

Check the events from RadioButton:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html

Then, into the method fired when `radioButton` state changes, change the state of the button like this:

```
button.setEnabled(true);
```